# Custom login/lock screen in OS X Mavericks

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-mavericks, sfauthorizationpluginview

I'm trying to override the default login/lock screen in OS X to allow the user to login in other way than providing a password (think fingerprint scanner or how "Knock to unlock" works), and I'm looking for a way to do it for hours now - all I found that looks useful is the Authorization Plugin ADC reference and this example: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NameAndPassword/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004022

This NameAndPassword xcode project is a little outdated, but I managed to build it simply by specifying the Base SDK (there was a hardcoded wrong path), then I put the resulting .bundle file into `/Library/Security/SecurityAgentPlugins` directory. Nothing changed after I locked my screen, but I know I need to add the authorization role to `/etc/authorization` file, which I know no longer exists in Mavericks (there is this auth.db file and the whole auth API), but I'm therefore stuck here - I don't know how to put NameAndPassword inside this database.

Please let me know how do I do it right, or if you know some other way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a way to edit the database - at first, I tried direct `/var/private/db/auth.db` sqlite modifications, but it didn't work, so after some time I managed to do this easier than I thought I will:

1. `security authorizationdb read system.login.console > outfile.plist`
2. After this, you need to modify the resulting `outfile.plist` as it's said in the NullAuthPlugin readme:

   ```
   <key>mechanisms</key>
     <array>
       <string>NameAndPassword:invoke</string>
   ```

   (the last line is the one you need to add to the file).
3. Then, to save it to the database:

   `security authorizationdb write system.login.console < outfile.plist`

Then the changes should be visible on any login/lock screen of your system, but **be careful!**

**You will not be able to authenticate with current version of NameAndPassword example!**

Be sure to estabilish a working SSH connection to your Mac **before** you modify the database, so you will be able to revert the changes using other device (just repeat the db modification process but this time remove the line you added before).

Comment: After executing these steps, I've been able to replace the authentication module used when the user logs out, or explicitly goes to the login screen. It appears that this custom login module is not used when the computer is restarted, or woken up from sleep. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: That's normal. This is a different mechanism. Not much you can do about it, except for some custom screensaver, at least as far as I know.