# How to add a custom authentication plugin for MacOS Ventura?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, authentication, sfauthorizationpluginview

I'm trying to create a custom authentication plugin for MacOS Ventura (instead of using a password i want to use a 4 digit code), and i was going to try and follow the code from this repository [NameAndPassword](https://github.com/skycocker/NameAndPassword), since i saw alot of positive feedback from this repository. But i follow the steps to add the .bundle file and update the authorizationdb but it just makes my MacOS stop working, after the Mac logo the screen just stays black.

I have follow the steps from this links:

[Creating an OS X authentication plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737444/creating-an-os-x-authentication-plugin)

[Custom login/lock screen in OS X Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582995/custom-login-lock-screen-in-os-x-mavericks/21618085#21618085)

[How to customize the Mac OSX login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45719864/how-to-customize-the-mac-osx-login?rq=3)

Does anyone know if for MacOS Ventura the configuration to add a authorization plugin have changed, and does anyone can confirm if the NameAndPassword plugin works for MacOS Ventura?