# Are there any up to date resources that explain AuthenticationPlugin development for MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, authentication

I'm attempting to develop an Authorization Plugin to display a window after the main Mac username and password authentication process. The problem is that Apple does not have much documentation on how to implement an authorization plugin and there is very limited documentation throughout the web that actually explains the functions and code. I am a novice when it comes to objective-c programming.

I have viewed the 'Let’s Make Some Decisions: Authorization Plugin Programming' video on YouTube, which is the only recent material I was able to locate. I followed the video and am still reviewing the code, but as I mentioned, I am a novice to objective-c and there is not much explanation for what I am trying to do.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcmql5byA_I

I expect a GUI window to display after a user enters their username and password to log into their profile. The GUI will eventually ask for a one time password, but for not I just want a GUI window to display.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845978/233944

Comment: @TheNextman, Thanks so much. Worked like a charm. You wouldn't happen to know any resources that talk about initializing pop up windows after authorization and before loading the user profile?

Comment: I don't know, sorry