# I want to add forgot password link to mac login screen

Tags: swift, macos

I want a way to add a clickable "password reset link" to the Mac login screen.
On clicking that link I want to call a mac os application. Is there any way programmatically customizing the macos login screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056322/customize-login-screen-mac-osx-sfauthorizationpluginview

Comment: Thank you. Can we invoke a mac os application from that link?